# Melhorar visualização do cabeçalho da tabela usando bootstrap 3.0.0, datatables e fixedHeader

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-datatables

Estou usando em um sistema o [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [datatables](https://www.datatables.net) e [fixedHeader](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/), estou com três problemas:

1. Eu precisaria que o cabeçalho (`thead`) da tabela parasse antes do final do menu, ficasse abaixo do menu, ele está parando no topo da página, tem como fazer isso?
2. Quando abro o `dialog` (clicando no *link* de cada linha no final) o `thead` fica por traz do *dialog*, mas é o único elemento que não fica por traz do modal (acho que é isso);
3. Quando clico em um menu, os items do sub-menu também ficam por de traz do `thead`;

O HTML, não gostaria de deixar aqui, por ser um tanto quanto extenso, mas se for o caso, eu até coloco;

O JS para fazer isso é esse

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "info": false
});

new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( oTable, {
  "zTop": "1035"
});
```

Segue os códigos aqui **http://jsbin.com/regetiyaki/1/edit?html,css,js**

E aqui já rodando o exemplo **http://jsbin.com/regetiyaki/1/**

PS: No momento estou com a versão 3.0.0 do bootstrap e não posso atualizar para a versão atual, no caso, 3.3.5, eu fiz esse teste e no caso solucionaria a minha questão 2, mas infelizmente não tenho como fazer essa atualização.

Segue um *print* dos erros, ai já da para perceber que o `thead` fica por cima do menu (no topo da página) e não fica por de traz do modal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcelo,

Você pode usar o `offsetTop` para fazer isso, exemplo:

```
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "info": false
    });

    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(oTable, {
        "offsetTop": 50
    });
```

Exemplo funcionando: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d8ar7ypf/1/)

Comment: Essa foi minha primeira tentativa, mas como é uma tabela com muitas colunas ficou tudo desconfigurado, em alguns casos eu estou usando dessa maneiro, mais simples mesmo e um plugin a menos, mas tem alguns casos que irei ter que usar o FixedHeader mesmo.

Comment: Entendi, eu estou usando desta forma,  da forma que você esta fazendo se você mudar o "zTop" para 1030 não irá aparecer o problema n° 2

Comment: para corrigir o problema 1° e necessario fazer uma verificação, ele fica fixo no top do body e e necessario que ele fique fixo no bottom do navbar...

Comment: Olha só, agora com essas alterações, de `zTop` e adicionando o `offsetTop` realmente já me resolve o primeiro e o segundo ponto, no caso, os principais, claro que o terceiro ponto também tenho que resolver, mas já me ajudou muito com esses dois. Valew mesmo!!!

Comment: voce pode diminuir o zTop para  1020 ou remove-lo que que todas as questões ficam resolvidas

Comment: Esta resposta está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4088/edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-que-altera-um-pouco-a-resposta-original

Comment: minha primeira ideia em resolver o problema foi usando o scroll, depois que testei o `offsetTop` vi que so precisaria dele para resolução de todas as duvidas do Marcelo, reeditarei com apenas aquilo que foi necessario para resolução do problema, obrigado Jorge.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz Rejeitei a edição, pois acredito que neste caso o autor deva editar e adicionar o `"zTop": "1020",`, mesmo estando comentado, talvez o zTop seja algo que funcionou pra ti, mas também pode ser o uso do html que afetou o Z, e neste caso o zTop só funcionaria pra ti. Recomendo que comente ao autor da resposta solicitando que ele adicione este trecho ao código, se ele achar que faz parte da resposta então OK, se não então o comentário dele deve bastar como "ajuda" para o seu problema. :)